Logging in Firefox ESR (v102.15.1) on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
I am trying to get Firefox-ESR to log HTTP connections.
Per: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/networking/http/logging.html
I should be able to do that by:
export MOZ_LOG=timestamp,rotate:200,nsHttp:5,cache2:5,nsSocketTransport:5,nsHostResolver:5
export MOZ_LOG_FILE=/tmp/log.txt

(or launching with these options).
However none of these seem to work.
Any ideas on how to force Firefox-ESR to log its activity?

What Operating System? What ESR version? Please [edit] the question.

MOZ_LOG seems relatively new. In older versions, the environment variables used to be NSPR_LOG_MODULES and NSPR_LOG_FILE.

Will check that, thanks. This is not mentioned in the docs.

No, it does not seem to be working either. I suspect whether Firefox does not need to be compiled with this somehow? Tried: DISPLAY=:0 firefox-esr --NSPR_LOG_MODULES=timestamp,rotate:2,nsHttp:5 --NSPR_LOG_FILE=/tmp/test.log ... => nothing, single dashes nothing either.

I don't think they ever worked as command-line options? Set them as environment variables, similar to how you used MOZ_LOG in your post.

Yes, export works. However, it does not seem that modules are respected. Because I see quickly filling up files with garbage of everything that the browser is doing: -rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   468K Nov  5 20:56 test.log.moz_log.0 -rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   513K Nov  5 20:55 test.log.moz_log.1 -rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   513K Nov  5 20:55 test.log.moz_log.2 -rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi   513K Nov  5 20:56 test.log.moz_log.3

Anyway, I am going to accept your answer, thanks for the help!
